# How to get two fields with the same Id

Tags: c#, .net, linq, graphql

I need to send two fields with the same Id in Altair(GraphQl).

```
mutation{
  createGoodsOrder(goodsorder: {
    deliveryDate: "2019-10-10"
    goodsOrderItems: [
      { orderItemId: 54 quantity: 1 costPerUnit: 1 goodType: INGREDIENT }
      { orderItemId: 54 quantity: 2 costPerUnit: 2 goodType: INGREDIENT }
    #  { orderItemId: 58 quantity: 2 costPerUnit: 2 goodType: INGREDIENT }
    ]
  }){
    id
  }
}
```

When I execute mutation, model contains both fields with the same Id but when I make `Fetch`, it returns only the first one. If It is not the same, Fetch returns both fields. How can I get both fields with the same Id?

```
var orderIngredients = _repository.Fetch<Ingredient>(e => model.GoodsOrderItems.Any(g => g.OrderItemId == e.Id)).ToList();
```

[image]

```
var orderIngredients = _repository.Fetch<Ingredient>(
                                        e => e.IngredientType.PlaceId == model.PlaceId
                                          && model.GoodsOrderItems.Any(g => g.OrderItemId == e.Id && g.GoodType == GoodsTypes.Ingredient))
                                        .Select(e => new GoodsOrderIngredientCreateModel
                                        {
                                            IngredientId = e.Id,
                                            Quantity = model.GoodsOrderItems.First(i => i.OrderItemId == e.Id).Quantity,
                                            CostPerUnit = model.GoodsOrderItems.First(i => i.OrderItemId == e.Id).CostPerUnit,
                                            TotalPrice = model.GoodsOrderItems.First(i => i.OrderItemId == e.Id).Quantity * 
                                                         model.GoodsOrderItems.First(i => i.OrderItemId == e.Id).CostPerUnit,
                                            GoodType = GoodsTypes.Ingredient
                                        }).Select(v => new GoodsOrderIngredient 
                                        {
                                            Id = v.Id,
                                            IngredientId = v.IngredientId,
                                            Quantity = v.Quantity,
                                            CostPerUnit = v.CostPerUnit,
                                            TotalPrice = v.TotalPrice
                                        }).ToList();
```

Mutation:

```
mutation.Field<GoodsOrderType>(
                name: "createGoodsOrder",
                arguments: new QueryArguments(
                    new QueryArgument<NonNullGraphType<GoodsOrderCreateInput>> { Name = nameof(GoodsOrder).ToLower() }
                ),
                resolve: context =>
                {
                    if (context.UserContext is GraphQLUserScopedContext userContext)
                    {
                        var goodsOrderService = userContext.ServiceScope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IVendorService>();

                        var model = context.GetArgument<GoodsOrderCreateModel>(nameof(GoodsOrder).ToLower());
                        model.PlaceId = userContext.User.PlaceId;
                        model.NetworkId = userContext.User.NetworkId;

                        var goodsOrder = goodsOrderService.CreateGoodsOrder(model);
                        return goodsOrder;
                    }
                    else
                        throw new ExecutionError(Constants.ErrorCodes.WrongUserContext);
                }).RequireAuthorization(PermissionsRequirement
                                                   .CreateForPermissionSetAll(
                                                       new Dictionary<NetworkPermissions, PermissionLevels>
                                                           { {NetworkPermissions.ERP_Cumulative, PermissionLevels.EditCreate} }));
```

Comment: Should ids not be unique?

Comment: @Tvde1 No, you can create two orders for apples: five good apples by 20$ and 3 bad apples by 5$

Comment: The code in the screenshot makes massive use of `First()`. Maybe that's where the problem comes from?

Comment: Would you please provide a [mcve]?

Comment: @ThomasWeller It is not because of `First` because I'm getting the same result with code example, provided in the question. Example: in `Ingredient` table I have 2 ingredients with Id 54 and 58. When In GraphQl I send two same Ids of ingredients, then `Fetch` in debug mode returns one field. If it is not the same, it returns two fields

Comment: show resolver code, not picture

Comment: @xadm Added full code, but it works just like it's short version in the first example

Comment: `model.GoodsOrderItems.Any` ... maybe `model.GoodsOrderItems.All(...` ?

Comment: @xadm In this case it return 0 items

Answer (score 0):

I don't know c# but probably you don't need intermediate types

```
                                  var orderIngredients = _repository.Fetch<Ingredient>(
                                    e => e.IngredientType.PlaceId == model.PlaceId
                                      && model.GoodsOrderItems.Any(g => g.OrderItemId == e.Id && g.GoodType == GoodsTypes.Ingredient))
                                    .Select(v => new GoodsOrderIngredient 
                                    {
                                        Id = v.Id,
                                        IngredientId = v.IngredientId,
                                        Quantity = v.Quantity,
                                        CostPerUnit = v.CostPerUnit,
                                        TotalPrice = v.Quantity * v.CostPerUnit
                                    }).ToList();
```

PS. If `GoodsOrderIngredientCreateModel` (for create mutation?) contains `TotalPrice` then total calculations are already in DB ?